# Javascript: Emulate typing of string without formatting, then output it with formatting

Tags: javascript, string, formatting, char, buffer

### Problem

---

Here's an interesting problem: (I'm not good at explaining so maybe look at the example first :P)

I have a string with (ansi) formatting codes and I want to output all chars of that string, with exception of all the formatting codes, in a way so it slowly builds up a string until a specific set of characters is found (§z) then output everything up to that point, but with the formatting codes. And start typing the rest of the message. Whenever §z is reached, print (with formatting) and start typing again (without formatting).

Oh and along the process something could be added to the "buffer"..
(So I can't just use .split("§z"))

### Example

---

Let's say I have this string:

> "[33;22m[1mWelcome![m§z<27> Hello[m "

The writer would then output a character every second until it reaches §z:

> Typing: W 
>   Typing: We 
>   *Until* Welcome!

Now it sees the §z and logs the first part but with formatting codes:

> Output: [33;22m[1mWelcome![m

Then it starts over and starts outputting the rest of the message:

> Typing: <
>   Typing: <2 
>   *Until* <27> Hello

Because there isn't any §z it stops and doesn't output anything.

**Now, suddenly** an event occurs that adds this to the string:

> Goodbye!§z

It would now go on typing:

> Typing: <27> Hello G 
>   Typing: <27> Hello Go 
>   *Until* Hello Goodbye!

Reached a §z so it would then output:

> Output: <27> Hello[m Goodbye!

### Code

---

I already have this code and it works, but all the formatting is lost.

```js
//TODO Work out this printing stuff...
var contentBuffer = "";

var displayContent = "";

var buffering = false;

var INPUT = "";


//Print function
function printMessage() {
    
 //Remove the formatting. The user doesn't type in formatted code, so we don't either.
    var noFormat = INPUT.replace(/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g, '');
 contentBuffer += noFormat;
 if(!buffering){
  buffering = true;
  buffer();
 }
}

function buffer(){
 if(contentBuffer != ""){
  if(contentBuffer[0] != "§"){
   displayContent += contentBuffer[0];
   document.write("Typing: " + displayContent + "<br />");
   contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(1);
  }else{ //Special sign handlers.
   if(contentBuffer[1] == "z"){
    //Echoing now! But our formatting is gone! :(
    document.write("Output: " + displayContent + " This output had to contain formatting, but we lost that on our quest to Mordor :(<br />");
    displayContent = "";
   }
   //Remove the newline code.
   contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(2);
  }
  setTimeout(buffer, 1000);
 }else{
      
  buffering = false;
 }
}

function suddenEvent(){
 document.write("<b>SUDDENLY AN EVENT OCCURED!</b><br/>");
 INPUT = "Goodbye!§z";
 printMessage();
}

//Run it:

INPUT = "\x1b[33;22m\x1b[1mWelcome!\x1b[m§z<27> Hello \x1b[m";
document.write("Input: " + INPUT + "<br /><br />");
printMessage();
setTimeout(suddenEvent, 25000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

---

Here's how I tackled the problem (for now):

I knew that every foramtting code started with an escape character and (becasue I was only using ansi-color formatting codes anyway) all of them ended with the letter "m". Like I said, simply splitting the string wasn't an option, instead I made two seperate strings. The buffer would append to both of these strings, except when it got to an escape character, then it would only append to one of them until the "m" was reached, then just continue with the normal behaviour.

### Code

---

```js
//TODO Work out this printing stuff...
var contentBuffer = "";

var displayContent = "";
var typeContent = "";

var buffering = false;

var INPUT = "";


//Print function
function printMessage() {
    
 //Remove the formatting. The user doesn't type in formatted code, so we don't either.
 contentBuffer += INPUT;
 if(!buffering){
  buffering = true;
  buffer();
 }
}

function buffer(){
  if(contentBuffer != ""){
    if(contentBuffer[0] == "§"){
      if(contentBuffer[1] == "z"){
        document.write("Output: " + displayContent + "<br />");
        typeContent = "";
        displayContent = "";
      }
      contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(2);
    }else if(contentBuffer[0] == "\x1b"){ //Escape character is detected!
      for(var i = 0, len = contentBuffer.length; i < len; i++){
        displayContent += contentBuffer[i];
        if(contentBuffer[i] == "m"){
          contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(i+1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }else{
      typeContent += contentBuffer[0];
      displayContent += contentBuffer[0];
      document.write("Typing: " + typeContent + "<br />");
      contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(1);
    }

    setTimeout(buffer, 1000);
  }else{
    buffering = false;
  }
}

function suddenEvent(){
 document.write("<b>SUDDENLY AN EVENT OCCURED!</b><br/>");
 INPUT = "Goodbye!§z";
 printMessage();
}

//Run it:

INPUT = "\x1b[33;22m\x1b[1mWelcome!\x1b[m§z<27> Hello \x1b[m";
document.write("Input: " + INPUT + "<br /><br />");
printMessage();
setTimeout(suddenEvent, 28000);
```

*It's not particulary clean, but it works the way I wanted it to.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand well the question. But if your question is **how to put in another color the document.write**, you can add `"<span style=\"color:green;\">"+output+"</span>"` to the output string.

(In this example, for green)

```js
//TODO Work out this printing stuff...
var contentBuffer = "";

var displayContent = "";

var buffering = false;

var INPUT = "[33;22m[1mWelcome![m§z<27> Hello [m";


//Print function
function printMessage() {
    
 //Remove the formatting. The user doesn't type in colors, so we don't either.
 contentBuffer += INPUT.replace(/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g, '');
 if(!buffering){
  buffering = true;
  buffer();
 }
}

function buffer(){
 if(contentBuffer != ""){
  if(contentBuffer[0] != "§"){
   displayContent += contentBuffer[0];
   document.write("Typing: " + displayContent + "<br />");
   contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(1);
  }else{ //Special sign handlers.
   if(contentBuffer[1] == "z"){
    //Echoing now! But our colors are gone! :(
    document.write( "<span style=\"color:green;\">Output: " + displayContent + " This output had to contain colors, but we lost them on our way to Bree :(</span><br />");
    displayContent = "";
   }
   //Remove the formatting code.
   contentBuffer = contentBuffer.slice(2);
  }
  setTimeout(buffer, 1000);
 }else{
      
  buffering = false;
 }
}

function suddenEvent(){
  document.write("<b>SUDDENLY AN EVENT OCCURED!</b><br/>");
 INPUT = "Goodbye!§z";
 printMessage();
}

//Run it:
document.write("Input: " + INPUT + "<br /><br />");
printMessage();
setTimeout(suddenEvent, 25000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but outputting in colors isn't my problem. The document.write(); is a placeholder anyway. I want my script to produce the behaviour I showed in the example. I've made a few chages to my post, I hope it's more clear now..